# Angular JS App ginving me uknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

I am following Brad Daley's Book on angular framework. In the console it leads me to the following

I have a simple angular 1.7.8 app however I keep getting the following error;

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider.
>   url : https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=configTimeProvider%20%3C-%20configTime%20%3C-%20controllerA

```
var configApp = angular.module('configApp1', []);
configApp.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value = ("configTime", new Date());
    $provide.value = ("runTime", new Date());
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        var y = Math.sqrt(Math.log(i))
    };
})//end config

configApp.run(function(configTime,runTime){
     runTime.setTime(new Date().getTime());                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
});
configApp.controller('controllerA', ['$scope', 'configTime', 'runTime',
  function ($scope, configTime, runTime) {
    $scope.configTime = configTime;
    $scope.runTime = runTime;
}])
```

The HTML is as a follows

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app = 'configApp1'>


<head>
<title>Configuration Run Blocks in Angular</title>
</head>

<body>


<div ng-controller = 'controllerA' >
    <h2>Config Time</h2>
    {{configTime}}
    <h2></h2>
    <hr>
    <h2>Run Time</h2>
    {{runTime}}
    <h2></h2>


</div>
<script src="../angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `$provide.value` as a method of the `$provide` service:

```
var configApp = angular.module('configApp1', []);
configApp.config(function ($provide) {
    ̶$̶p̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶(̶"̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶T̶i̶m̶e̶"̶,̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶e̶(̶)̶)̶;̶
    $provide.value("configTime", new Date());
    ̶$̶p̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶.̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶(̶"̶r̶u̶n̶T̶i̶m̶e̶"̶,̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶e̶(̶)̶)̶;̶
    $provide.value("runTime", new Date());
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        var y = Math.sqrt(Math.log(i))
    };
})//end config
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $provide Service API Reference - value](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/api/auto/service/$provide#value)